# How do I slide up a div off container with moving effect in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/XiangXu/rf6tdw4s/17/

```
<button id="slide">slide it</button>
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
  <div class="innerTop" id="top">Slide from top</div>
  <div class="innerBottom" id="bottom">Slide from bottom</div>
</div>

.slide {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.slide .innerTop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.slide .innerBottom {
    position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

$("#slide").click(function() {
  $("#top").slideToggle();
  $("#bottom").slideToggle();
});
```

The bottom one is no problem which moves down off the container.
But the top one is like there is something erasing it from bottom to top instead of moving it!

How do I move it off the container like the bottom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with toggling a css class.

- Add a class `hidden` when want to hide it
- set position of the elements out of the box making it negative
- set `overflow:hidden` of the container.

Here is a working example:

```js
$("#slide").click(function() {
  $("#top, #bottom").toggleClass("hidden"); // toggle CSS class on click
});
```

```css
.slide {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* setting overflow hidden */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.slide .innerTop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.slide .innerBottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  transition: 0.25s linear;  /* adding animation */
}

#top.hidden {
  top: -30px;  /* making out of the visible area */
}

#bottom.hidden {
  bottom: -30px; /* making out of the visible area */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="slide">slide it</button>
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
  <div class="innerTop" id="top">Slide from top</div>
  <div class="innerBottom" id="bottom">Slide from bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am glad I could help you. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with jQuery's `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` function because it animates `height` of the element. However you can add `class` on `click` and use css `transform` for styling them.

```js
$("#slide").click(function() {
  $("#top, #bottom").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.slide {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide .innerTop,
.slide .innerBottom {
  transition: transform 0.25s linear;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.slide .innerTop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.slide .innerTop.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.slide .innerBottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.slide .innerBottom.hidden {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="slide">slide it</button>
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
  <div class="innerTop" id="top">Slide from top</div>
  <div class="innerBottom" id="bottom">Slide from bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too. But the syntax for transform is different for other browser? I need to use -webkit-transform for my safari to work. Chrome no problem tho.

Comment: @Jack If your browsers are up to date then vendors prefixes are not needed however you can use `webkit` and `ms` prefix to avoid cross browser issues. Using css transformation is better because it gives you flexibility to slide elements with flexible height i.e slide will work perfectly if your content goes in multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely use it :) And yes, it can do a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example,

```js
$("#slide").click(function() {
  $("#top").slideToggle();
  $("#bottom").slideToggle();
});
$("#slideDown").click(function() {
 $("#top").slideDown();
 $("#bottom").slideDown();
});
$("#slideUp").click(function() {
 $("#top").slideUp();
 $("#bottom").slideUp();
});
```

```css
.slide {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  
}

.slide .innerTop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #acacac;
}

.slide .innerBottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #acacac;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script><button id="slide">slide it</button>
<button id="slideDown">slide Down</button>

<button id="slideUp">slide Up</button>
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
  <div class="innerTop" id="top">Slide from top</div>
  <div class="innerBottom" id="bottom">Slide from bottom</div>
</div>
```